# how to remove the default sales Team in search view from pipeline in odoo 9

Tags: xml, python-2.7, odoo-9

Consider the cirecle area , when i click on the **your pipeline** , then the **Sales Team** added in serch box by default and filter the view . so i have no idea how to remove this as a default.

[image]

so if you have any idea how to remove this as a default , please share with me .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the pipeline from the filter you can follow the following step.

> Step 1  Activate the **developer mode.**

Then

> Step 2 Go to **setting -> Technical -> Action -> Window action -> Filter
>   -> remove 'search_default_assigned_to_me': 1**

[image: Remove-from-the-default-filter]

Comment: Thanks @Ravi, but through this , i only remove **My Opportunities** insted of **Direct Sales** .

Comment: Hello check, this second answer you surely get the solution.

Answer (score 1):

> I got the point and the problem you are facing.
>   **Follow the above answer to remove the opportunity.**
>
> ```
> This to remove the sales lead.
> ```

To remove that you do follow the following steps.

### Step 1 activates the developer mode.

### Step 2 Edit search view

> To do that task go to Sales **-> Your Pipeline -> then click on the
>   drop-down of the debug mode -> and click the edit search view.** as
>   shown in the image below.

[image: Remove-from-default-search]

### Step 3 Remove Team Id

> now in the edit search view **remove the Team ID** as shown in the Image
>   Below.

[image: Remove-team-ID]

Comment: Heartily welcome. Its request plz up vote previous answer also. As its part of the answer.